# Enabling cors on a method in the template.yaml with the implicit API

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-sam

I'm trying to enable Cors for the Stack RestAPI and all its methods whenever I deploy. I've managed to do it manually by creating an Empty Model, and then setting it up as the response alongst with statusCode 200.

Problem is, I don't want it to get reset and have to manually change it. The closest I've found so far was Someone else that suggested something like this:

```
  OptionsMethod:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
    Properties:
      AuthorizationType: NONE
      RestApiId: !Ref MyApi
      ResourceId: !GetAtt MyApi.RootResourceId
      ...
```

I've tried modifying it to every flavor I could think of by replacing `MyApi` with `ServerlessRestApi` which seems to be the implicit Rest Api. I can't figure out how to make it work except by creating another API than the implicit one.

In short, I want the cors to be enabled by default when I deploy my/a new lambda function.

Comment: Setup an options method which can handle your CROS pre-flight request, then incorporate your CORS headers in the integration/request methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set CORS globally in your yaml:

```
Globals:
  Api:
    Cors:
      AllowMethods: "'OPTIONS,POST,GET'"
      AllowHeaders: "'*'"
      AllowOrigin: "'*'"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to include Cors headers in your Lambda function response (as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html#apigateway-enable-cors-proxy)), more specifically:

```js
{
    body: {...},
    headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" : "X-Requested-With,Content-Type",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "https://www.example.com",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS,POST,GET"
}
```